# how i can remove and adding 2 attributes sequentially when it was choosen jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm new in this jquery. 
Here's the code that i make :

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value="Message">Message</option>
    <option value="Order">Order</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="Message">
<input type="text" id="Order" disabled>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#selector").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "Message"){
                $("#Order").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("#Message").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else($(this).val() == "Order")
            {
                $("#Message").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("#Order").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

how i can make my input disabled when it was choosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the if condition after the else.

Here is the modified code:

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value="Message">Message</option>
    <option value="Order">Order</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="Message">
<input type="text" id="Order" disabled>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#selector").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "Message"){
                $("#Order").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("#Message").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else if($(this).val() == "Order") // add if here
            {
                $("#Message").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("#Order").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here is your working code.](https://jsfiddle.net/tyyv7cjb/)

Comment: @Wilx : My pleasure to remind you. accept the answer.